# SQL Table- Copying data of different data type tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I am working on scenario, i have two tables:
"**Master_product**" and "**New_Products**"

**Master_product** table have 14 fields 
and 
**New_Products** table have 16 fields, some fields are same between both table but different data-types than **Master_product**

now i want to copy record to **Master_product** from **New_Products**, 
i tried update syntax but it is giving error regarding data-types. That it can't be processed due to different data types.

is there is any way to update **Master_product**

Comment: Add some tables and code please

Answer (score 0):

There are two operators, cast and convert, that might help you in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert from the 2 types using [convert or cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), then you might be able to do it:

```
Update Master_product set some_column = Convert(int,other_column) from New_Products
```

Comment: well, thanks for reply... i will check this whether it works for me or not